# Very slow Entity Framework Core query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on an Entity Framework Core query that gets really slow with a large amount of data. The database structure looks like this:
[image: Structure]

I want to create a query that will check whether the address of a customer has already been used. I came up with this query for that:

```
    public bool IsNew(string name, int shopId, AddressModel addressModel)
    {
        return !this.Entities.Customers
             .Where(c => c.Name == name && c.ShopId == shopId)
             .Select(c => c.Address)
             .Where(a => a.City == addressModel.Name)
             .Any(s => s.PostalCode == addressModel.PostalCode);
    }
```

This query is very slow if a Shop has a lot of customers with the same name (which doesn't make sense but this is not the real database).

So my question is: how can the performance of this query be improved? This is an ASP.NET Core Web API project.

This is the generated SQL-query:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM [Customers] AS [c]
              INNER JOIN [Address] AS [r.Address] ON [r].[AddressId] = [r.Address].[Id]
              WHERE ((([r].[Name] = 'name') AND ([r].[ShopId] = 1)) AND ([r.Address].[City] = 'Amsterdam')) AND ([r.RequestBrowser].[PostalCode] = '4444XX'))
          THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
      END
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you add indexes on the columns you use for lookup?

Comment: And why do you need three separate conditions? Isn't it the same as simply doing `this.Entities.Customers.Any(c => c.Name == name && c.ShopId == shopId && c.Address.City == addressModel.Name && c.Address.PostalCode == addressModel.PostalCode)`?

Comment: Why is City varbinary?

Comment: @GertArnold That seems to be a mistake in my ERD (I just created it to make my question more understandable)

Comment: @Imantas There is an index on Customers.Name and Customers.ShopId. I used your query before but it also had a bad performance. I created mine becuase I thought it might improve the performance.

Comment: OK, well, first thing to check when ef-core is slow is: which queries does it execute and does ef switch to client-side evaluation? Second thing to check is the query plan for missing indexes. We can't do either.

Comment: I checked and ef does not switch to client-side evaluation. I also checked the execution plan. There it gives me a warning: Columns with no statistics on Customers.AddressId.

Comment: Profile, profile, profile. SQL Profiler is your best friend.

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL query?

Comment: Added SQL query to my question.

Comment: Try doing all the conditions without the 'select'in the middle, and try to retrun the count ,instead of a boolean result, thus might generate some less offensive tsql

Comment: *no statistics on Customers.AddressId* OK, try to add statistics. Also, test the query in the database engine tuning advisor. It doesn't look exceptionally brutal at all.

Comment: @Menahem Count is not an improvement. An EXIST-query is about the cheapest query there is.

Comment: Another quite likely improvement (and standard recommendation anyway) is to normalize the City field into a City table. That reduces the city name search to one record and the addresses are found by a simple join.

Comment: @Gert Arnold i didnt say count is better. I said it might produce better tsql, since the select case is aggressive

Comment: The SQL query looks good, so it's not a problem with EF Core query translation. Sounds like bad execution plan due to lack of proper indexes or parameter sniffing (I'm sure the actual SQL query generated by EFC contains parameters). What if you know the `AddressId`, e.g. how is `!this.Entities.Customers.Any(c => c.Name == name && c.ShopId == shopId && c.AddressId == someAddressId)` is performing compared to the original?

Comment: @IvanStoev with c.AddressId == someAddressId the query is very quick. Does that mean I need indexing in City and PostalCode?

Comment: @kjwdamme Probably - you could try and see. It really falls into database optimizations category. From pure C# and programmer point of view, all I can think of is to split the query in two parts (execute two queries instead of one) - something like `var addressIds = this.Entities.Addresses.Where(a => a.City == addressModel.Name && a.PostalCode == addressModel.PostalCode).Select(a = a.Id).ToList(); and then `return addressIds.Any() && !this.Entities.Customers.Any(c => c.Name == name && c.ShopId == shopId && adddressIds.Contains(c.AddressId));`